# HTTP Header - CONTENT_LENGTH vs HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH

Tags: iis, http-headers

I am working with a classic asp website on an IIS web server.

When I look at the `request.serverVariables` collection (which contains request http headers and server variables, etc.), I am seeing the following two, which in my specific set-up are producing 100% identical values.

```
CONTENT_LENGTH
HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH
```

In the mozilla docs, it lists `[Content-Length][1]` as:

> The Content-Length entity header is indicating the size of the entity-body, in bytes, sent to the recipient.

I think it's refering to what I am seeing as [`HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length)

Then, in the IIS docs for Server Variables, it lists [`CONTENT_LENGTH`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables) as

> The length of the request body.

Is this just an IIS thing where the `CONTENT_LENGTH` is just the server's own internal copy of the `HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH` header sent back? (or do I have that backwards)?

Is there any difference between the two e.g. some other cases where the values of each could be different if a certain scenario occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH is specific to IIS, and in fact returns the raw value of the CONTENT_LENGTH header.  (CONTENT_LENGTH is available on all server environments).

For reference, this Visual COBOL documentation Server Variable's Reference page lists this and many other IIS specific variables.
http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2FGUID-80E5C7E2-6B33-40F2-AA69-CA301927FA8F%2FGUID-AB547FFE-B2EF-44A2-95BE-3B26175C158B.html

Comment: So then `HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH` is a completely redundant copy of the standard http header (`CONTENT_LENGTH`)? E.G. there would be no possible cases of theses two containing different values?

Comment: affirmative, the values would always be identical.